# Are linear subspaces of euclidian spaces closed

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a linear subspace of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^N$.
Is $\mathcal{S}$ necessarily closed?

Comment: Yes. Hint: Singletons are closed, and linear subspaces are preimages of singletons.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: Just to fix my mind. Do you mean a vector subspace, don't you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am an engineer, could you please  give me a more intuitive hint if it is possible.

Comment: Yes, I mean vector subspaces.

Comment: Another basic (and rudimentary) approach is to start from the definitions, and use the fact that all norms are equivalent in finite-dimensional vector space in [tag:functional-analysis].

Comment: Hint toward another approach: construct a basis for the subspace. Note the basis must be finite. Then consider possible limit points of sequences in the subspace.

Comment: Then, according to [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space) for each $n\in \mathbb N$ there is one and only one (up to isomorphism [I guess homeomorphism]) topological vector space. It follows from this that any finite-dimensional vector subspace of a topological vector space is closed."

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, vector subspaces are closed.  Here's an explanation that you might find intuitive.

Let $P$ denote the (orthogonal) projection onto $\mathcal S^\perp$, the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal S$.  Of course, $x$ is an element of $S$ if and only if $Px = 0$.  Moreover, $P$ is a continuous map.

It follows that if $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of points from $\mathcal S$ converging to $x$, then $Px_n$ must converge to $Px$.  Since $Px_n = 0$ for all elements $x_n$, we must have $Px = 0$, and thus $x \in \mathcal S$.

So, whenever $x_n$ is a convergent sequence of points in $\mathcal S$ with limit $x$, we have $x \in \mathcal S$.  Thus, $\mathcal S$ is a closed set.

Comment: The terser version of this argument is what Tobias said, namely that $P^{-1}(\{0\})$ must be closed.

Comment: Based on your proof, every linear subspace is closed!

Comment: @BashirSadeghi indeed: in a finite dimensional normed vector space (such as a Euclidean space), every linear subspace is closed.  In infinite dimensional spaces, the projection map $P$ might not be continuous or well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

If you pick the basis correctly, the every linear subspace $W$ of $\mathbb R^N$ just looks like

$$W = \{ (x_1, ... , x_t,0, ... , 0) \in \mathbb R^n \}$$

which is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: Such a change of basis will not generally preserve the Euclidean (i.e. inner-product) structure on $\Bbb R^N$, so a more flexible definition of the topology may be needed